# ModernCV enumerated list of references?

Tags: bibtex, moderncv

I'm trying to use modernCV to construct a CV. I'd like to use multibib to get an enumerated list of my journal publications, separate from my conference publications. I can't seem to get any of the standard BibTex styles to give an *enumerated* list of publications, though, they all render without numbers (e.g., I'd like the bibliography to have [1] [2] [3] before the entries). My MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}

\moderncvstyle{classic}    
\moderncvcolor{green}  
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}
\newcommand{\itcs}{Innovations in Theoretical Computer Science}
\usepackage{multibib}
\newcites{cp,misc}{{Conference Proceedings},{Journal Publication}}

\firstname{}
\familyname{}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand*{\bibliographyhead}[1]{}
\makecvtitle


\section{Journal Publications}
\nocitecp{*} % cite your books
\bibliographystylecp{unsrt}
\bibliographycp{publications} % 'publications' is the name of a BibTeX file
\section{Conference Publications}
\nocitemisc{*} % cite other elements
\bibliographystylemisc{unsrt}
\bibliographymisc{techreports} % 'publications' is the name of a BibTeX file

\end{document}
```

with publications.bib and techreporst.bib both containing:

```
@book{ab94,
   author = {Charalambos D. Aliprantis and Kim C. Border},
   year = {1994},
   title = {Infinite Dimensional Analysis},
   publisher = {Springer},
   address = {Berlin}
 }
```

Does anyone know why unsrt, which normally gives a bibliography which is enumerated, not do so in this case?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! I have no idea but, just in case, did you try with `biblatex`? It defaults to `numeric` style, which is more or less `unsrt`, and it uses the concept of `bibliography sections` (§ 3.6.5 of the doc).

Comment: @Bernard `moderncv` and `biblatex` don't like each other!

Comment: @Harish Kumar: Ahah! Didn't know that. So the solution should consist in having a hand made bibliography, I suppose?

Comment: @Bernard But then there is: http://ctan.org/pkg/koma-moderncvclassic to make them compatible.

Comment: @Harish Kumar: I wasn't aware of that one. Quite interesting… Thanks for the tip.

Comment: @Bernard, thank you! That worked perfectly. I used biblatex to create multiple subsections of publications more easily than with multibib.